# Getting cursor row in contenteditable div (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

I need to get learn where is my cursor on contenteditable div.

when I press enter, contenteditable div creates a "" as a row. just like:

```
<div class="contenteditable" contenteditable="true">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

then, I need to learn, in which row is my cursor, then I'm gonna append some html codes in it.

How can I do this with jquery?

Comment: Explain what **cursor on contenteditable** div is ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's insertAfter() function for this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr8Gf/)

```
$('.contenteditable div').click(function() {
  $('<div>New Div</div>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

When you click on one of the divs inside contenteditable, it inserts a new div right after it.  I added the text 'New Div' to make it more obvious where the new entry went.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
var $div=$('div'), isEditable=$div.is('.editable');
$div.prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable') })
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wu4VD/65/

**Edited later:**
I think you want that!
 on event click, on div for edit, to see the row (index or id)

```
    <div class="contenteditable" contenteditable="true">
    <div id="1">Some text 1</div>
    <div id="2">Some text 2</div>
    <div id="3">Some text 3</div>
    <div id="4">Some text 4</div>
```

```
$('.contenteditable div').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
```

Click [**here to see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu4VD/74/)

Comment: what does it works for? i doesn't tell, in which row is my cursor?

Comment: First of all you must define more accurate what you want. In a page you can't use ENTER, you will use mouse click. use table insted of divs, there are a lot of solution, but first I don;t understand exactly what you want. PS read a HTML documentation first.

Comment: Have you tested my example made it for you ?? in alert you see the number of row where you clicked !!   http://jsfiddle.net/Wu4VD/77/

Comment: Still I can't say where on what line my cursor is. This answer in useless